# How to create a list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

My problem is not exactly creating the list, but I create it according to the norms of my country. The list should look like this

Figure 1 - Caption   (white space or dotted) 6

It should start with the word figure followed by its numbering, then a dash, then its caption and in the right corner of the page the number of the page where it appears.

There is a class called abntex2 that does this, but I could not make it work using the book class. Some commands contained in the abntex2 class that are related to the list of figures are

```
\renewcommand{\cftfigurename}{\figurename\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftfigureaftersnum}{\hfill\textendash\hfill}
```

Add un minimal code (need any figure called 1)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\cftfigurename}{\figurename\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftfigureaftersnum}{\hfill\textendash\hfill}

\begin{document}

\pdfbookmark[0]{\listfigurename}{lof}%need \usepackage{hyperref}
\listoffigures*
\cleardoublepage

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{1}
\caption{Test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What class are you using currently (or want to use)?

Comment: As a Brazilian, I am shame because of this absurd rules in `abnt`.

Comment: These are commands from `tocloft`. Try loading it and add these commands to your preamble. Do you want page number to be right after captions or at the end of  lines, with one figure per line?

Comment: I don't see what's so absurd. Each country has its own typographical rules.

Comment: @Bernard, just my opinion. But when we read all the rules, we start to be crazy. Specially to format the text in TeX.

Comment: But why should every scientific text look like a U.S. text? I'm sorry, but I use A4 paper, not letter paper, and my layout is done according to French typographical rules.

Comment: @Werner I want to use in class book. @Bernard error appears `\cftfigurename undefined. \renewcommand{\cftfigurename}`

Comment: @Bernard I need page number to be at the end of lines.

Comment: You should post a minimal code showing the problem.

Comment: @Bernard ok, added

Comment: @MarceloRodrigues: The macros are called `\cftfigname` and `\cftfigaftersnum` and there is no `\listoffigures*` macro in the `book` class -- it will leave a stray `*` after your list of figures

Comment: You should use a **class** that does this by default -- such as `abntex2`. Just replace `\documentclass{book}` with `\documentclass{abntex2}`. Or just use a **package** called `abnt` with the `book` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way. I supposed you won't have more than 99 figures (one has to compute the width of the label in the list of figures). I also added the `emptypage` package, to have no header/footer on empty pages.

Also, as mentioned by @ChristianHupfer, the hand-made `\pdfbookmark[0]{…}` can be replaced with loading package `tocbibind`  with option `[notoc]` so that the table of contents does not refer to itself.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe} 
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand*{\cftfigname}{\figurename\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftfigaftersnum}{~\textendash\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\cftfigname}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{\widthof{\cftfigname 00~\textendash~}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{figure}{49}

\chapter{Some Chapter}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds. You could use `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` to get rid of that weird manual `\pdfbookmark` stuff.

Comment: Done, mylord ! – with due credits. That is  a really useful comment, as I hadn't tested  what happens in the table of contents.

Comment: I can't upvote twice, however ;-)

Comment: @Bernard Thank you very much. I was able to make the list of tables using the same commands, I just substituted `fig` by `tab`.

Comment: @Bernard: I know that French like to omit the letter 'H', at least in pronounciation, but you kept it in my name (which is correct), but you dropped the letter `f` in my name ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Sorry. One of my many typos – unless it was a *lapsus calami*: perhaps it subconsciously stood for ὑπέρ ;o)