# Style of chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I modified the list of figures and list of tables with help that I got [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415336/how-to-create-a-list-of-figures)

The problem is that the summary, the list of figures and the list of tables do not follow the same formatting of the chapters. Without the modifications to the list of figures and list of tables the problem does not occur

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=2cm, left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}    
%%%%%%    CHAPTER           %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{10\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \thickhrulefill\quad
        \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter %Original \bfseries no lugar de \scshape
        \quad \thickhrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \hrule
        \vskip 70\p@ % 100
}}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{10\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \thickhrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \Huge {\scshape #1}\par\nobreak %original bfseries
        \par
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \hrule
        \vskip 50\p@ % 70
}}    
% LIST OF FIGURE
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tocloft} 
\renewcommand*{\cftfigname}{\figurename\space} 
\renewcommand*{\cftfigaftersnum}{~\textendash\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\cftfigname}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{\widthof{\cftfigname 00~\textendash0~}}
\addto\captionsbrazil{\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Lista de ilustra\c{c}\~{o}es}}   
% LIST OF TABLES
\renewcommand*{\cfttabname}{\tablename\space} 
\renewcommand*{\cfttabaftersnum}{~\textendash\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{\cfttabname}
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{\widthof{\cfttabname 00~\textendash0~}}

\begin{document}    
\tableofcontents    
\listoffigures   
\listoftables    
\chapter{Some chapter}    
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Any things}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \hline 
    a & b \\ 
    \hline 
    c & d \\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\caption{Any table}
\end{table}    

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The `tocloft` package has its own views about typesetting the chapter headers of `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures` etc.

Use `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}` to switch back to regular behavior, i.e. getting control back as is done for `\@makechapterhead` and `\@makeschapterhead`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=2cm, left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}    
%%%%%%    CHAPTER           %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{10\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \thickhrulefill\quad
        \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapter %Original \bfseries no lugar de \scshape
        \quad \thickhrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \hrule
        \vskip 70\p@ % 100
}}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{10\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \thickhrulefill
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \hrule
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \Huge {\scshape #1}\par\nobreak %original bfseries
        \par
        \vspace*{10\p@}%
        \hrule
        \vskip 50\p@ % 70
}}    
% LIST OF FIGURE
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} 
\renewcommand*{\cftfigname}{\figurename\space} 
\renewcommand*{\cftfigaftersnum}{~\textendash\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{\cftfigname}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{\widthof{\cftfigname 00~\textendash0~}}
\addto\captionsbrazil{\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Lista de ilustra\c{c}\~{o}es}}   
% LIST OF TABLES
\renewcommand*{\cfttabname}{\tablename\space} 
\renewcommand*{\cfttabaftersnum}{~\textendash\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{\cfttabname}
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{\widthof{\cfttabname 00~\textendash0~}}

\begin{document}    
\tableofcontents    
\listoffigures   
\listoftables    
\chapter{Some chapter}    
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Any things}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[H]\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \hline 
    a & b \\ 
    \hline 
    c & d \\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabular} 
\caption{Any table}
\end{table}    

\end{document}
```